# MFC do while loop

Tags: c++, mfc, while-loop, do-while

I am doing a measurement system and I have got a do while loop in my program. In the loop, it is checking if any motor is moving before it could take measurement as it require it to reach the target position before doing anything.

While doing the measurement, it is suppose to tell me how long does it took to do this measurement.

However, whenever it runs in the do while loop, all my timer function stop as if they are put to Sleep mode.

Is there any other method where I could implement this? If there is, please help me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
SetTimer(TIMERECHO, 1000, NULL);

BOOL bMoving = FALSE;
do
{
    if (IsMoving(ID, NULL, &bMoving)) 
        GetPosition();
} while (bMoving);


void CLHMDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    switch(nIDEvent)
    {
        case TIMERECHO:
            UpdateData(FALSE);
            m_Seconds++;
            m_TimerEcho.Format(_T("Total time: %ds"), m_Seconds);
            break;
    }
    CDialogEx::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MFC has a message loop that gets and dispatches messages such as WM_TIMER. If you do a while loop that message loop is not running. It's not sleeping, it's just waiting  until you stop hogging the processor.

You have two options: (1) Get rid of the lengthy loop and do whatever it does periodically on a WM_TIMER message. (2) Use a second thread to do the lengthy operation. This has numerous difficulties for a beginner.

Comment: How am I suppose to code it such that I won't get the while loop to hog the processor?? Can you please help me in this? Thank You

Comment: Instead of looping use a timer to do the test periodically. Every time you do the test return to MFC. That is the way to not hog the processor.

Comment: If you care about how much CPU your app is using, don't sit in a tight loop checking the time.  Use one of the callback-based timers available in Windows (see the link in my response above)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your loop isn't processing messages.  onTimer is called as a result of a windows message.  You need to keep processing messages in the loop or use a callback based timer.

One method is using CreateTimerQueueTimer
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, I'm a beginner in MFC programming.

Comment: A callback based timer still needs a message loop - the callback is just invoked by `DefWindowProc`.

Comment: No, a "callback" timer doesn't need a message loop if it's one of the versions of the descendants of the MM timers of old, such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution (but not perfect) to get you running is to move your `IsMoving` to the timer as below:

```
void CLHMDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    switch(nIDEvent)
    {
        case TIMERECHO:
           if (IsMoving(ID, NULL, &bMoving)) 
              GetPosition();

            UpdateData(FALSE);
            m_Seconds++;
            m_TimerEcho.Format(_T("Total time: %ds"), m_Seconds);
            break;
    }
    CDialogEx::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

However for a proper solution you have to use threads for this, the complexity of that will vary for simple to better solutions there as well. I have written some code on the fly for you, it may not compile but you get the idea.

```
AfxBeginThread(monitor_motor, this);

UINT monitor_motor(LPVOId lParam)
{
CMyDlg * dlg = (CMyDlg *) lParam;
HWND hWnd = (HWND) dlg->m_hWnd;


do
{
    if (IsMoving(ID, NULL, &dlg->bMoving)) 
        GetPosition();

    Sleep(100); // maybe you don't have to poll too hard and give other hardware chance to communicate?..that's upto you

    PostMessage( hWnd, UPDATE_TIMER_AND_STUFF );
} while (dlg->bMoving);

PostMessage( hWnd, UPDATE_MOTOR_MOVED_COMPLETELY );

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But is there a need to call this thread in my measurement? I have a `OnMeasurementStart`. Do I need to include the thread in my button?

Comment: Yes that would be the best approach. I am actually doing a similar thing myself, there is not too much resources on this topic in relation to use threads in such cases.

Comment: What I mean is, how do I call the thread into my button?? @zadane

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly but use AfxBeginThread() to start the thread when you press the button

Comment: Okay, but where do I include `AfxBeginThread(monitor_motor, this);` ?? In the header file or in the CPP file? @zadane

Comment: Okay, Got another problem. When I inserted everything into my CPP file, my `ID` in `IsMoving` is undefined. The ID is an int in my header file. @zadane